# OpenAPI use server with host only, not port?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

I've been reading the [OpenAPI specification](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/api-host-and-base-path/) regarding `API Server and Base URL` to try and figure out how to dynamically create the server based on the host. There is a section on `Relative URLs`, but it takes both the `IP` and the `port` where I need just the `IP`.

My setup:
Server with API: `10.0.0.10`
Server with OpenAPI implementation: `10.0.0.10:1234`
Server object in openapi.json: `"servers": [{"url": "/x.y.z"}]`
[swagger-ui](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/docs/usage/installation.md#plain-old-htmlcssjs-standalone): Standalone option where it generates the page based on my `openapi.json` file

This generates a page where it lists `/x.y.z` as the server and uses `10.0.0.10:1234/x.y.z` as the URL. This is doesn't work because the actual API is on `10.0.0.10/x.y.z`.

So, I don't think relative URL will work for me. On the same page the documentation references using variables. Are there built-in variables/keywords? Something like `"servers": [{"url": "{HOST}/x.y.z"}]` where `{HOST}` would return `10.0.0.10` (and for example if you wanted the port you could use `{PORT}`). If not, is there any way I can achieve what I need?

I've tried to search, but the topics I'm finding are unrelated. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56764572/does-openapi-3-0-allow-to-reference-server-variables) for example comes up in my searches, but it's asking about references which isn't related. Other results are similar. The closest I've found is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37157721/override-host-and-basepath-at-the-path-level), but it's referencing overriding for different paths which is also unrelated.

Comment: Can the user who voted this down explain why? As far as I can tell with my searches this isn't a duplicate question.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct solution, but I did find a workaround using variables.

```
"servers": [{
  "url": "http://{host}/x.y.z",
  "variables": {
    "host": {
      "default": "127.0.0.1"
    }
  }
}]
```

This produces a new `Server variables` subsection to the `Servers` section. It lets you manually modify the specified variable(s) here. While it's not automatic it at least lets me manually modify the IP.

I'd still prefer an automatic method, but posting this in case it helps anyone as a workaround.